# Псевдокласс jQuery  (hover) для одного элемента

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вот в чем проблема, есть див

```
 <div id="my">dfg <a href="fb.com">TEXTS1</a> asd dfg <a href="vk.com">TEXTS2</a> asd, dfg <a href="odkl.ru">TEXTS3</a> asd</div>
```

и есть код Jquery

```
$("#my a").hover( function () {   $("#my a").addClass("thisc");  },  function () {   $("#my a").removeClass("thisc");  } );
```

Дело в том, что если нацелить мышь на 1 тег "а", то светятся все, как сделать, чтоб светился только на который курсор (без привязки к атрибуту хреф, то есть не сравнивать, если хреф равно тому; понял, что можно через .each, но не получается что-то)?

Answer (score 4):

`$(this)` в теле функциий вместо `$("#my a")`:

```
$("#my a").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("thisc");
},  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("thisc");
});
```